# Linear regression with multiple observations for each input point: WLS approach

Tags: least-squares, linear-model

Consider a dataset $X, y$ where each $y$ is distinct, but many of the rows of $X$ are repeated.

Suppose that there are indices $\{ i_j: j = 1  \dots J \}$ such that the consecutive rows $X_{i_j}=X_{i_j+1} \dots = X_{i_{j+1}-1}$ are all identical.

Will I get the same result if I work with a reduced dataset $\tilde{X} = ( X_{i_j} : j = 1 \dots J)$ and $\tilde{y} = \left( \frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{k=i_j}^{i_{j+1}-1} y_k : j = 1 \dots J\right)$ where $n_j = i_{j+1}-i_{j}$ and use WLS with weights $w = (n_j: j = 1 \dots J)$?

Here's a "proof":

The gradients (score function) are the same for both regressions:

$$ 2X'(X\beta - y) = 2\tilde{X}' W (\tilde{X} \beta - \tilde{y})$$

where $W = \mathrm{diag}(w)$.

Is the above correct?

If so, is there a name for this?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer.

Let $J$ be the number of unique $x$ observations, $n_j$ the number of times observation $x_j$ is repeated and $\{y_{j,i} : 1 \le i \le n_j \}$ the corresponding $y$ observations.

For a regression model $y = f(x, \beta) + \varepsilon$ the loss is given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_J} \left( y_{j,i} - f(x_j, \beta) \right)^2
&= \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_J} \left( y_{j,i} -  \overline{y}_j + \overline{y}_j - f(x_j, \beta) \right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_J} \left( y_{j,i} -  \overline{y}_j \right)^2 + \left( \overline{y}_j - f(x_j, \beta) \right)^2 + 2 \left( y_{j,i} -  \overline{y}_j \right)\left( \overline{y}_j - f(x_j, \beta) \right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_J} \left( y_{j,i} -  \overline{y}_j \right)^2 + \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_J} \left( \overline{y}_j - f(x_j, \beta) \right)^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The first term doesn't depend on $\beta$, which concludes the proof that the $\beta$s are the same.

The estimates of the residual variance will obviously differ between the two methods.